# Not in scope: `catch'

Tags: haskell, scope

I am reading learn you a haskell for great good but i faced an error of Not in scope: `catch' when I read the exception section in input & output chapter

here is my code:

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.IO.Error  

main = toTry `catch` handler  

toTry :: IO ()  
toTry = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
           contents <- readFile fileName  
           putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"  

handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e = putStrLn "Whoops, had some trouble!"
```

and I get this error message:

```
Not in scope: `catch'
```

Comment: note: you can always use hoogle to search for something like that http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=catch

Comment: This presumably arose because `catch` used to be in the `Prelude`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`catch` is exported by the `Control.Exception` module.

```
import Control.Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `import System.IO.Error` you can use `catchIOError` instead of `catch`.

Link: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#v:catchIOError

Source:

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.IO.Error  
  
main = toTry `catchIOError` handler  
              
toTry :: IO ()  
toTry = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
           contents <- readFile fileName  
           putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"  
  
handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e = putStrLn "Whoops, had some trouble!"
```

Calling:

```
runhaskell catch.hs non_existing_file.txt
```

Output:

```
Whoops, had some trouble!
```